# SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position

Tags: json, mongodb, react-native, mongoose, postman

**Why do I get this error every time I use the api (POST)**

SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 18
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parse (/Users/.../Desktop/ecommerceapi/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
at /Users/.../Desktop/ecommerceapi/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (/Users/.../Desktop/ecommerceapi/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
at done (/Users/.../Desktop/ecommerceapi/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/.../Desktop/ecommerceapi/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:532:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

**This is my entire code: (auth.js)**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    ).toString(),
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne(
            {
                userName: req.body.user_name
            }
        );

        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");

        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            user.password,
            process.env.PASS_SEC
        );


        const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        const inputPassword = req.body.password;
        
        originalPassword != inputPassword && 
            res.status(401).json("Wrong Password");

        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
            id: user._id,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        },
        process.env.JWT_SEC,
            {expiresIn:"3d"}
        );
  
        const { password, ...others } = user._doc;  
        res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});

    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using Postman to use the API to POST this

`{     "username": sultan     "password": 12345qwer }`

and this is index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
mongoose = require("mongoose")
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

dotenv.config();

mongoose
.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
.then(() => console.log("DB Connection Successfull!"))
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 50, () => {
    console.log("Backend server is running!");
});
```

it should give me the users Info or "Wrong Password" but it gives the above error as a response!

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Where did you get this from

Comment: can you double quotes "sultant" and "12345qwer" ?

Comment: @tkausl what do you mean is not a valid JSON, I followed a tutorial on YouTube and that's exactly what's written it worked with the guy who wrote this code but it didn't with me. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @l4rnaud I tried double quotes but also didn't work. Thanks for replying.

Comment: `I followed a tutorial on YouTube and that's exactly what's written` Then the video is wrong or the video is hiding something. Thats just invalid JSON, period.

Comment: @tkausl can you please tell which part of the code is wrong? I edited the question please re-check it. Thanks.

Comment: @l4rnaud told you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double quotes and comma are missing
{
"username": "sultan",
"password": "12345 qwer"
}